# Unable to run jepsen test for either elasticsearch or rabbitmq

Tags: testing, elasticsearch, clojure, rabbitmq, jepsen

I seem to be missing something basic as I try to run the tests @ https://github.com/abailly/jepsen-vagrant

Here is the output for the rabbitmq test profile in lein :

```
lein test :only jepsen.system.rabbitmq-test/rabbit-test

ERROR in (rabbit-test) (Session.java:512)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect (Session.java:512)
    com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect (Session.java:183)
    clj_ssh.ssh$connect.invoke (ssh.clj:327)
    jepsen.control$session.invoke (control.clj:182)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:624)
    jepsen.core$fcatch$wrapper__4829.doInvoke (core.clj:39)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:408)
    clojure.core$pmap$fn__6328$fn__6329.invoke (core.clj:6463)
    clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__4145.invoke (core.clj:1910)
    clojure.lang.AFn.call (AFn.java:18)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 1 errors.
Tests failed.
Error encountered performing task 'test' with profile(s): 'base,system,user,provided,dev,rabbitmq'
Tests failed.
vagrant@jepsen:/jepsen/jepsen$
```

How can I fix this. I did all the steps mentioned for auth fix in both https://github.com/aphyr/jepsen/tree/master/jepsen and https://github.com/abailly/jepsen-vagrant steps...

Comment: I added a question to committers on these github project locations @ https://github.com/aphyr/jepsen/issues/46. No luck so far ..........

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of additional thing to check when working with code that uses jsch

- make sure ssh-agent knows the password for the key you are using. Use ssh-add to do this.
- use a key (ie ~/.ssh/id_rsa) for that host which does not have a password. Be sure to set this on the project explicitly. In this case the readme mentions setting it in the project config.
- make sure you can ssh to the host using the same key manually by running "ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@host " and read the output to make sure it's using the key you think it is.
- add logging set the log level in your project for ’com.jcraft.jsch’ to debug and ensure that it's using the user you think it should be. This may be more or less practical depending on how your project has logging configured. I have often had jsch based projects try to use empty usernames.
- try running the project from a different host with different key configurations to see if it's a local environment issue (usually in my experience related to ssh-agent)

And best of luck to you, every jsch based project breaks in it's own ways though the problems are almost always solvable.

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out the step in the jepsen-vagrant github which requires passing the location or the contents of the ~/.ssh/id_rsa to core::run! e.g., for testing rabbitmq. Any suggestions/tips ?